# How can svelte ease between two colors?

Tags: svelte, tween

Does svelte have built-in support for tweening/easing between two colors, or should I write my own interpolation function for that?

I want a div to change background color, and I could supply the CSS color any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in support for this, you have to add this yourself. The [API docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#tweened) however show you exactly this example as a custom tweener using `d3-interpolate`

```html
<script>
    import { interpolateLab } from 'd3-interpolate';
    import { tweened } from 'svelte/motion';

    const colors = [
        'rgb(255, 62, 0)',
        'rgb(64, 179, 255)',
        'rgb(103, 103, 120)'
    ];

    const color = tweened(colors[0], {
        duration: 800,
        interpolate: interpolateLab
    });
</script>

{#each colors as c}
    <button
        style="background-color: {c}; color: white; border: none;"
        on:click="{e => color.set(c)}"
    >{c}</button>
{/each}

<h1 style="color: {$color}">{$color}</h1>
```

Comment: I don't know if the API was updated recently, but the `rgb()` format is not applicable anymore for the `interpolateLab` function. Using a HEX string like #00ffbb works just fine, though.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this example](https://svelte.dev/repl/073c71dbdd9c4250b2ad5c9343e2e053?version=3.26.0) I created the following custom interpolation:

```ts
import { tweened, type TweenedOptions } from "svelte/motion"

const tweenedHex = (
    hexadecimalString: string,
    options: TweenedOptions<string>,
) => {
    const decimalToHex = (decimal: number) =>
        Math.round(decimal).toString(16).padStart(2, "0")

    const getColor = (hex: string, index: number) =>
        parseInt(hex.slice(index, index + 2), 16)

    const getRGBs = (hex: string) => [
        getColor(hex, 1),
        getColor(hex, 3),
        getColor(hex, 5),
    ]

    const scaledValue = (start: number, delta: number, t: number) =>
        start + delta * t

    function rgbInterpolate(fromColor: string, toColor: string) {
        const [fromRed, fromGreen, fromBlue] = getRGBs(fromColor)
        const [toRed, toGreen, toBlue] = getRGBs(toColor)
        const deltaRed = toRed - fromRed
        const deltaGreen = toGreen - fromGreen
        const deltaBlue = toBlue - fromBlue

        return (t: number) => {
            const red = scaledValue(fromRed, deltaRed, t)
            const green = scaledValue(fromGreen, deltaGreen, t)
            const blue = scaledValue(fromBlue, deltaBlue, t)
            return (
                "#" +
                decimalToHex(red) +
                decimalToHex(green) +
                decimalToHex(blue)
            )
        }
    }

    const color = tweened(hexadecimalString, {
        ...options,
        interpolate: rgbInterpolate,
    })

    return {
        ...color,
        setAndExecuteAction: async (
            newHex: string,
            actionCallback: () => unknown,
        ) => {
            await color.set(newHex)
            actionCallback()
        },
    }
}

export default tweenedHex
```

And then, I use this custom interpolation in the same way as in the following example component:

```svelte
<script lang="ts">
    import tweenedHex from "../store/tweenedHex"

    let color = "#ff0000"

    const tweenedColor = tweenedHex(color, {
        duration: 1000
    })

    $: tweenedColor.setAndExecuteAction(color, () => {
        console.log("Interpolation Ended!")
    })
</script>

<span>
    <input
        type="color"
        name="color-input"
        id="color-input"
        bind:value={color}
    />
    <span style:font-size="32px" style:color={$tweenedColor}>
        Tweened Color
    </span>
</span>

<span>color = {$tweenedColor}</span>
```

I'm still quite inexperienced with the framework, but this way I was able to meet all the needs related to color transitions within my svelte components. Hope this helps!